# Don't update HTML when angular $scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have `for` loop in my JS:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    $scope.widget = widgets[i];
    $scope.header = widgets[i].data.header;
    $scope.items = widgets[i].data.items;
    $scope.footer = widgets[i].data.footer;
    var widget = widgets[i];
    var div1 = '<div id="' + widget.id + '" class="' + widget.width +'" >';
    var div2 = '<div class="panel" style="background-color:' + widget.color +';color:white;">';
    var header = widget.body.headerTemplate;
    var panelStart =  '<div class="panel-collapse pull out">';
    var widgetBody = widget.body.itemTemplate;
    var widgetFooter = widget.body.footerTemplate;
    var panelEnd = '</div>';
    var div2End = '</div>';
    var div1End = '</div>';
    var widgetHTML = div1 + div2 + header + panelStart + widgetBody + widgetFooter + panelEnd + iv2End +iv1End;
    console.log(widgetHTML);

    var linkingFunction = $compile(widgetHTML);
    var elem = linkingFunction($scope);

    $(elem).appendTo("#widgetsContainer");
}
```

Which append some HTML to div container. In that HTML there are data-binding like this:

```
<a href='{{header.redirectUri}}'>{{header.title}}</a>
```

Of course, $scope variables changes every time it loops, and in the end all scope variables update HTML with last values. Is it possible to not update HTML after it is drawn?

Comment: create another boolean variable which tell when to append and then execute above code inside if condition using that boolean

Comment: or append the string value rather than the variable, to the html to keep html static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - introduced in angular 1.3.x - **one-time binding**

```
<a href='{{::header.redirectUri}}'>{{::header.title}}</a>
```

And for ng-repeat do this:

```
'ng-repeat="item in ::items"'
```

Read more at [Exploring Angular 1.3 - One-time bindings](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)

Comment: Works great, just to add, for ng-repeat do this: 'ng-repeat="item in ::items"'

Comment: @firstChild glad to hear, added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use one way binding , if you use Angular 1.3.x then use

```
<a href='{{::header.redirectUri}}'>{{::header.title}}</a>
```

or use [bind-once](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)